# License application android to unlock usefull

Tags: android

I would like to implement a license system in my Android application, have you any idea about this system?

I think a file crypted contains informations about licence?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think, you should have a look at the [Google Play Billing](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_overview) feature, which can give you the possibility to charge user for one time purchase, monthly subscription or yearly subscription. You can see exemplary usages in the official Google/Android repository here: https://github.com/android/play-billing-samples. As far as I know, this is the most common practice to unlock app features or charge users for the "full version" of your app and it's integrated with the Android OS.

Comment: I have problems with backend server sample. Do you believe it works?

Comment: I don't have much experience with this, but it's official Google/Android sample, so that's the first thing, which should work.

Answer (score 0):

I don't want use GooglePlay services, i share the apk by my personnal link.

Comment: Then, you can use external server for that, but I'm not really sure if this won't violate Google Play Policy in case of distributing app in the Google Play Store.

Comment: I don't want use a server, i want to verify in local mode.